# URL amigável não recupera variável

Tags: php, htaccess

Estou tentando deixar as URLs do meu site amigável.

URL amigável

```
 http://localhost/mg/artista/10
```

.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On

  RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d

  RewriteRule ^/artista/([0-9]+)$ /artista.php?artista=$1
</IfModule>
```

PHP para recuperar a variável

```
$artista = $_GET['artista'];
```

Está dando o seguinte erro: Notice: Undefined index: artista

Vi em alguns lugares o pessoal recuperando a variável usando $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']. Se eu uso isso, ele me retorna: /mg/artista/10. Dando um explode conseguiria pegar a variável, mas não sei se essa é a forma correta.

Answer (score 1):

O problema com seu `.htaccess` é que na regra

```
RewriteRule ^/artista/([0-9]+)$ /artista.php?artista=$1
```

o `^/` no começo indica que o path *deve* começar com `/artista`. Como no seu caso o path começa com `mg/`, a regra é pulada.

Para que funcione você só precisa remover o `^/` do início da regra.

Ex.:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On

  RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d

  RewriteRule /artista/([0-9]+)$ /artista.php?artista=$1
</IfModule>
```

Nota: Caso ainda não conheça, [**aqui**](http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/) você pode encontrar uma ferramenta muito boa pra testar o htaccess.

Comment: obrigado pela dica da ferramenta, não conhecia. Tirei o "^/" e o erro permaneceu o mesmo. Será que o erro não está na recuperação da variável? Abs

Comment: Vi em alguns lugares o pessoal recuperando a variável usando $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']. Se eu uso isso, ele me retorna: /mg/artista/10. Dando um explode conseguiria pegar a variável, mas não sei se essa é a forma correta.

Comment: @Ricardo Tente tirar o `/` antes de `artista` e veja se funciona pra você.

Comment: @AndréRibeiro O problema talvez seja `$` no final da expressão não bastava apenas remover `^` do início. Assim parece funcionar: `RewriteRule /artista/([0-9]+) /artista.php?artista=$1`.

Comment: @AndréRibeiro não adiantou tirar o /

Comment: @QMechanic73, também não funcionou

Comment: To achando que o erro não está no .htaccess e sim na recuperação da variável...

Comment: @Ricardo Então é algum problema com seu apache.

Answer (score 0):

RewriteRule ^/artista/([0-9]+)$ /artista.php?artista=$1 [QSA,L]

https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteFlags/QSA